# Was there an explanation as to how Gods came to be in The Iron Druid Chronicles?

Tags: books, iron-druid

So I'm curious if there was ever an in canon explanation of where all the Gods came from in The Iron Druid Chronicles? Most places I remember seeing stated that the gods are kind of thought-form where if people believed in something then they come into existence...

Comment: I think I remember that somewhere there is a discussion of the Tuatha Dé Danann being human druids who got so powerful they became gods.  That's part of why they are relatively easily killed.  Not sure about other pantheons.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I found the same reference. I'd encourage you to post that as an answer, that's about as close as I think you will come.

Comment: Thanks...found a couple more reference which, I think, cover it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it's every stated in plain English how gods come into being but by *inference* gods (with a small "g") are created by belief systems....they just ARE.

> "The problem with the Tuatha Dé Danann was that they were not beings of pure magic, like their descendants born in the land of Faerie: They were beings of this world, who merely used magic better than anyone else, and the Irish had long ago elevated them to gods."
>
> <sup>*Hounded* by Kevin Hearne</sup>

There can also be *multiple* versions of gods...Thor for instance

> “I’ve read the old stuff, and I know that you’re after Thor version 1.0. But you know, there’s more than one version of Thor out there now, just like there are multiple Coyotes and various versions of Jesus and Buddha and Elvis. We can invade Asgard, kill Thor 1.0, and then, if we manage to avoid getting creamed by the rest of the Norse, we could come back here to Midgard only to have the comic book Thor smite the hell out of us like the naughty varlets we are."

There's a line in *Hunted* when Odin says..

> "Humanity has created more powerful gods."

..and in *Hexed*..

> “So in a sense it’s we with faith who create gods, not the gods who create us. And, if that’s the case, then it’s we who created the universe.”

It's implicit in that statement that gods are *created* by humanity not other beings that exist outside of their belief systems.

Comment: The newest/last book has some more explicit discussions with a particular god.  (Vague for spoilers sake.)

Comment: Oooh...it's out! That's going on my Kindle tonight.